# Objective c MailCore message body

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, mailcore

I'm trying to get the body of a Mail with MailCore but it's always empty.
My code is

```
    CTCore *folder = [[CTCorefolder alloc] initWithPath:@"INBOX" inAccount:account];
for( CTCoreMessage *msg in [folder messageObjectsFromIndex : 0 toIndex:10] ){
   if([msg.subject isEqualToString:@"test")]){
         // no pb here, it find the good Mail
         NSLog(@"Message Body length : %d", msg.body.length);
         // here the length is 0 and the body is : ""
  }
}
```

There are other way to get the body, like "msg.HtmlBody" but it is empty too.
However on firefox I can see the body which isn't empty.
How should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must call `fetchBody` on each message in order to retrieve it from the server.